# How to deploy a MERN application in heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mern

My application has a NodeJS server, ReactJS client and database MongoDB compass. I need to deploy this to Heroku. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried searching? Is there a specific error that you are getting in some way to deploy?

Comment: Create two different Heroku apps for react JS and node JS project

Comment: get on youtube, and watch traversy media's mern full stack development, at the last video he explains how to deploy to heroku